# Arduino not working the same when powered with battery, not usb

Tags: arduino, battery

So, I'm building an Arduino toy car. It runs with 4 motors and has 2 color sensors and 8 IR sensors. It must work on battery because i don't want it to be hooked to USB all the time and motors require much more current than USB can provide. So here's the problem...

When I have my arduino powered with USB cable or USB cable and battery, it works perfectly, but when I have it powered only on battery (7.2V), 4 LED's in the left color sensor glow dimmer, and the right one doesn't even work.

I should point out that some of the pins of color sensor that should be plugged in 5V or GND are plugged in digital output pins set on `HIGH` or `LOW`.

The arduino i'm working on is Arduino Mega 2560 and color sensors are TCS230.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should measure supply current of the board and then check if your battery is able to provide such value. Also try to feed the board from external supply through wall adapter connector (or Arduino's Vin terminal). The idea is that you may need higher voltage and(or) current, then 7,2V.

Comment: I have a 11 volt battery and it doesn't work either. And USB cabel has 5V voltage so i don't think it's about that.

Comment: I noticed that if connect high load, such as motors, rf modules e t.c. arduino voltage may become lower than 5V, sometimes i received about 3.6V at 5V pin. This is because arduino built in 5V line regulator can source max 1A. If load is higher it will reduce its output voltage.
Also if you will look at arduino's schematic you can find protection diode, which will have drop voltage about 0,5V, Line regulator have 1.2V drop at 800mA, so if you need at least 6.8 at load of 800mA. 
Check if you battery is able to source such current, best of all is to check the voltage using oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have the correct resisters values in place to drive the LEDs. You can sometimes get away without doing so but it is iffy and you can sink a lot of current you don't really need to. I found this link, ["Driving LEDs with an Arduino"](http://sheepdogguides.com/arduino/aht0led.htm).

Comment: I don't use resistors, LEDs are built in color sensor.

Comment: If the LEDs are built into the board, they should be setup correctly. Different USB ports have different current capabilities. One of my PC USB ports can drive my dev board, 2 LEDs, a 2 line color LCD display and a temperature sensor without problems. In contrast, my MAC USB port can't drive them without external power.